# WordPress Rest API [invalid_username]

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

For some reason, I'm getting the above error when trying to create a product through WordPress Rest API.
It looks like the WP account might have a password authentication issue.

Has anyone had this issue before and/or know how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Use the same username as the one you use to log in to the site's dashboard. Make an application password for that username. You can do that from near the bottom of your user profile page.